# Need to create a Python 2.7 Dice roller which determines a characters stats

Tags: python

I need to create a short program which allows a user have their stats created using a dice rolling method.
It has to create 2 different stats, a Strength attribute, and a Skill Atribute. For these to be created it has a 12 sided dice rolled, and a 4 sided dice rolled. The value of the 12 sided dice is then divided by the 4 sided dice for the Strength Attribute, this is then repeated for the Skill Attribute.
That's all, I'm not sure where to go about with this and any help would be thanked very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? (As I'm sure you know, StackOverflow won't just write a project for you).

Comment: sounds like homework.  Show some code!

Comment: `I'm not sure where to go about with this`. Advice for you can be only -- learn some books on Python and on Math. Close this question (because, no one will answer your question here), and create new one, where you give us part of your **probably not working** code, and describe your problem. Welcome to StackOverflow, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely take a look at the random module in the stdlib [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)

You can then you can do stuff like:

```
import random

random.randint(1,12) 
# which produces random number between 1-12
```

That should get you going.

Comment: @Volatility yes updated! keyboards man.

Comment: Yeah I had something slightly similar to this, just wasn't sure were to go with it, I probably should have put the code which I had in just it wasn't that much, sorry about that. Thanks. :)

Comment: @user2047609 consider accepting it as  an answer if it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is (as myusuf3 pointed out):

```
stat = random.randint (1, 12) / random (1, 4)
```

or

```
stat = random.randint (1, 12) // random (1, 4)
```

whether you want fractions or not.

Now, if you will use more dice later in the game (for attack rolls, skill rolls, etc) with different number of sides (d4, d6, d8, d10) etc, you can create your own Die class (which would surely be overkill for your example, but I will sketch it just to give you an idea):

```
class Die:
    def __init__ (self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll (self, times = 1):
        return sum (random.randint (1, self.sides) for _ in range (times) )
```

So, at the beginning you can instantiate your dice:

```
d4 = Die (4)
d6 = Die (6)
d10 = Die (10)
```

Now, if for instance you make an damage roll with 5d10, you can simply type:

```
damageRoll = d10.roll (5)
```

--

Just to take this idea even further, you could create your own Weapon class with a ADnD damage notation (e.g. 2d4+1 meaning, roll two dice with four sides, sum the results and add 1):

```
import random
import re

class Weapon:
    def __init__ (self, name, dmg):
            self.name = name
            self.dmg = dmg
            self.dice, self.sides, mod, iMod = re.match ('(\\d*)d(\\d+)(?:([+-])(\\d+))?', dmg).groups ()
            self.dice = int (self.dice) if self.dice else 1
            self.sides = int (self.sides)
            self.mod = 0 if not iMod else int (iMod) * (-1 if mod == '-' else 1)

    @property
    def damage (self):
        return max (0, sum (random.randint (1, self.sides) for x in range (self.dice) ) + self.mod)

w = Weapon ('Bad ass katana', '4d10+8')
for i in range (10):
    print (w.damage)
```

Comment: Aha thank you very much, I probably should have put the code which I had in just it wasn't that much, sorry about that. Thank you for answering my questions everybody, very helpful.